# Неправильно работает код

Tags: c++, структуры

Вся база не выводится, выводятся только вторые введенные значения

```html
#include "pch.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

struct Weather //cтруктура "Погода"
{
 string local; //район місцевості
 int data; //дата
 int count; //кількість опадів
 double intensity; //інтенсивність опадів
 double speed; //швидкість вітру
 int temp; //середня температура 
 string direction; //напрямок вітру
 string afternoon; //температура вдень
 string night;//температура вночі
} s[100];
int add(int n) //Добавление информации в базу
{
 char ch;
 do {
  cout << "mestnost': " << endl;
  cin >> s[n].local;
  cout << "data: " << endl;
  cin >> s[n].data;
  cout << "\tosadki: \n" << endl;
  cout << "kol-vo: ";
  cin >> s[n].count;
  cout << " intensivnost': " << endl;
  cin >> s[n].intensity;
  cout << "\tveter \n";
  cout << "skorost': " << endl;
  cin >> s[n].speed;
  cout << "napravlenie: " << endl;
  cin >> s[n].direction;
  cout << " srednya temperatura v techenii dnya: " << endl;
  cin >> s[n].temp;
  cout << "den': " << endl;
  cin >> s[n].afternoon;
  cout << "noch': " << endl;
  cin >> s[n].night; 
  system("cls");
  cout << "najmite lubuu klavishy chtobi prodolgit' krome y \n";
  cin >> ch;
 } while (ch != 'y');
 return ++n;
}
void Out(int n) //Вывод базы
{
 cout << "\t\t ________________________________" << endl;
 cout << "\t\t|\tINFORM PRO BAZU:\t |";
 cout << "\n";
 cout << "\t\t|--------------------------------|" << endl;
for (int i=0; i<n;i++)
{
  cout << "\t\t|mestnost': " << s[i].local << "\t\t" << "|";
  cout << "\n\t\t|data: " << s[i].data << "\t\t \t |";
  cout << "\n\t\t|\tosadki: " << "\t         |";
  cout << "\n\t\t|kolichestvo: " << s[i].count << "\t\t" << " |";
  cout << "\n\t\t|intensivnost': " << s[i].intensity << "\t\t" << " |";
  cout << "\n\t\t| \tveter: " << "\t\t\t |" << "\t\t ";
  cout << "\n";
  cout << "\t\t|skorost': " << s[i].speed << "\t\t\t" << " |";
  cout << "\n\t\t|napravlenie: " << s[i].direction << "\t\t" << " |";
  cout << "\n\t\t|sredneya  temperatura: " << s[i].temp << "\t |";
  cout << "\n\t\t|den': " << s[i].afternoon << "\t\t\t |";
  cout << "\n\t\t|noch: " << s[i].night << "\t\t\t |" << endl;
  cout << "\t\t|________________________________|" << endl;
 
}

 system("pause");
 system("cls");
}
void t(int n) // Температура в местности с +10
{
 int dat = 0;

 cout << " vvedite daty: ";
 cin >> dat;
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
 {
  cout << "vivod inform \n" << endl;
  if (s[i].data == dat && s[i].temp == +10)
  {
   cout << "mestnost':  " << s[i].local << endl;
  }
  else
   cout << "zdes' ne bilo temperaturi +10 " << endl;
 }

 system("pause");
 system("cls");
}
void average(int n) //Среднее количество осадков
{
 string loc;
 int day;
 cout << " dobavit' mestnost': ";
 cin >> loc;
 cout << "vvedite den': ";
 cin >> day;
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
 {
  if (s[i].local == loc)
  {

   if (day != 0) // якщо виконується умова
   {
    double precipitation = (double)s[i].count / day;
    cout << "srednee kol-vo osadkov: " << precipitation << endl;
   }
   else
    cout << "srednee kol-vo osadkov = 0" << endl; // якщо не виконується умова
  }

 }
 system("pause");
 system("cls");
}
void wind(int n) //Определение направления ветра
{
 string locaal;
 int date;
 cout << "mestnost': " << endl;
 cin >> locaal;
 cout << "data: " << endl;
 cin >> date;
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
 {
  if (s[i].local == locaal)
  {
   if (s[i].data == date)
   {
    cout << "napravlenie bilo: " << s[i].direction << endl;
    cout << " data: " << s[i].data << endl;
   }
   else
    cout << "zdes' takogo net! " << endl;
  }
  else
   cout << "error! " << endl;
 }
 system("pause");
}

int main()
{

 int n = 0;
 while (1)
 {
  cout << "\t\t\t\tMenu" << endl;
  cout << "\t\t---------------------------------" << endl;
  cout << "\t\t|\t1 - dobavit'\t\t|" << endl <<
   "\t\t|\t2 - vlya baza\t\t|" << endl <<
   "\t\t|\t3 - mestnost' gde 10\t|" << endl <<
   "\t\t|\t4 - srednie osadki\t|" << endl <<
   "\t\t|\t5 - napravlenie vetra\t|" << endl <<
   "\t\t|\t6 - exit\t\t|" << endl;
  cout << "\t\t---------------------------------" << endl;
  int a; cin >> a;
  switch (a)
  {
  case 1:
   system("cls");
   n = add(n);
   system("cls");
   break;
  case 2:
  
   Out(n);
   break;
  case 3:
   system("cls");
   t(n);
   break;
  case 4:
   system("cls");
   average(n);
   break;
  case 5:
   system("cls");
   wind(n);
   system("cls");
   break;
  case 6:
  {exit(0);
  default:
   exit(0);
  }
  }
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша функция `add` позволяет ввести инфоpмацию для нескольких объектов, но счетчик увеличивает только один раз.

```
int add(int n) //Добавление информации в базу
{
    char ch;
    do {
        cout << "mestnost': " << endl;
        cin >> s[n].local;
        ...
        cout << "noch': " << endl;
        cin >> s[n].night;  

        n++;
        system("cls");
        cout << "najmite lubuu klavishy chtobi prodolgit' krome y \n";
        cin >> ch;
    } while (ch != 'y');
    return n;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Вы мой спаситель!